# Joining Colums in Python using Panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I am trying to join tables of 6 months into only one colums in Python. However I am not sure why it is giving me so much trouble. Any help?

```
df.Dates = df[["1 Month Date","2 Month Date","3 Month Date","4 Month Date","5 Month Date","6 Month Date"]]
df.Dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(df.Dates)
```

Here is the error:

```
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-83667cbe6215> in <module>
      1 df.Dates = df[["1 Month Date","2 Month Date","3 Month Date","4 Month Date","5 Month Date","6 Month Date"]]
----> 2 df.Dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
      3 print(df.Dates)
      4 #Dates = df[["1 Month Date","2 Month Date","3 Month Date","4 Month Date","5 Month Date","6 Month Date"]].apply(pd.Series.explode).sum(axis=1)
      5 #print(Dates)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2900             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2901                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2902             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2903             if is_integer(indexer):
   2904                 indexer = [indexer]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'Dates'
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data - e.g. 3 rows 3 columns and add expected ouput?

Comment: the right side of the 1st line will give you the dataframe you can't use df.date or df['date'] on left side it'll not gonna work. I guess you wanna concat all these columns for that please use str method

Comment: col_list = ["1 Month Date","2 Month Date","3 Month Date","4 Month Date","5 Month Date","6 Month Date"] df.Date = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(str(x[col]) for col in col_list), axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.Dates = df[["1 Month Date","2 Month Date","3 Month Date","4 Month Date","5 Month Date","6 Month Date"]]
```

The above line gives a warning on pandas 1.2.3

```
UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
```

So to create a new column, you'd better use `df['Dates']`

What's more, by using a list of columns to select columns, pandas will return a dataframe. You are actually assigning a dataframe to a Series.

To join columns values, you can use `apply` on rows with `axis=1`, then convert row values to array and join them with proper separator.

```py
cols = ["1 Month Date","2 Month Date","3 Month Date","4 Month Date","5 Month Date","6 Month Date"]
df['Dates'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: ''.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

Comment: When I print it is not giving me the expected outpur , which is the list of all the dates of the 6 months ::

Comment: 0     2020-09-01T00:00:00.0000000002020-10-01T00:00:...
1     2020-09-01T00:00:00.0000000002020-10-01T00:00:...
2     2020-09-01T00:00:00.0000000002020-10-01T00:00:...
3     2020-09-01T00:00:00.0000000002020-10-01T00:00:...
4     2020-09-01T00:00:00.0000000002020-10-01T00:00:...
5     2020-09-01T00:00:00.0000000002020-10-01T00:00:...
7     2020-09-01T00:00:00.0000000002020-10-01T00:00:...
8     2020-09-01T00:00:00.0000000002020-10-01T00:00:...
9     2020-09-01T00:00:00.0000000002020-10-01T00:00:...
10    2020-09-01T00:00:00.0000000002020-10-01T00:00:...

Name: Dates, dtype: object

Comment: Plus it results into an object but I need Date time

Comment: @XIUJY1111 What do you mean by join? Append all to one column?